# Ceiling lights powered, but not from main panel

Tags: electrical

My contractor seems to be creating energy from thin air. He uncovered some old wiring while replacing the ceiling plaster in my living room. I had him use this wiring to install low voltage can lights and they look great. As I was installing a smart switch, I was unable to locate a circuit breaker in my main panel that was powering these lights. We had a new main panel installed 7 years ago, could the old wiring have simply been missed when wiring the panel? Could it somehow be directly connected to the main line coming in the house and be unfused?

Comment: Can you have someone get a tone-tracer on those mystery wires?  Have you tried turning your main breaker off and seeing if the lights in question stay on?

Comment: Is this a single family dwelling?  Or a multi-tenant? How old is the construction?  Did you try turning your main breaker off?

Comment: Not wise to use "old wiring" without knowing exactly where it is supplied from. Poor decision on both your part and the contractor...

Comment: Single family home built in 1908 with extensive remodels (all knob and tube removed). You're right, it is on the master switch, I didn't try that before. I'll get the electrician to wire it up to an unused circuit breaker.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Glad you figured it out; would you post this as an answer to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is "the panel's main switch" at the main panel, or is it somewhere else?  Because hotwiring a lighting circuit straight off the main breaker *in the same panel*,  **is such an obviously wrong thing to do** that I seriously doubt anyone actually did it.  Methinks you have another panel somewhere.

Comment: @Harper - no other panels in the house. The original 100 amp panel was upgraded 8 years ago to 200 amps. At the time, the wiring being used now was hidden above a plaster ceiling and obviously wasn't fused to the new panel but left on the main circuit. No idea why. The new electrician clearly tried to get away with something - fortunately I haven't paid for the work yet so he's coming back to fix his shoddy work.